# Python + SQLAlchemy: how to update many-to-one relationship after one of relation's object field change?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-3.5, many-to-one

I have three declarative_base models.

```
class Region(BaseModel):

    id                      = BaseModel.column(type='integer', primary_key=True)
    # ...
    y1                      = BaseModel.column(type='float')
    y2                      = BaseModel.column(type='float')
    x1                      = BaseModel.column(type='float')
    x2                      = BaseModel.column(type='float')
    map_id                  = BaseModel.column(type='mediumint')

    units = relationship('Unit', primaryjoin="and_((Region.id == Unit.region_id), (Unit.unit_template_id))")

    players = relationship('Player', lazy='subquery')


class Unit(BaseModel):

    # ...
    region_id               = Object.column(type='integer',
                                        foreign_key=db_name + '.region.id',
                                        nullable=True)

    region                  = relationship('Region', lazy='subquery')

class Player(Unit):

    # ...
    unit                    = relationship('Unit', lazy='subquery')
```

As you can see, `Player` inherits `Unit`. `Region` contains list of units and list of players. When I change any player field inherited from unit, the region's `players` relationship does not refreshes. What should I do after changing `Player` field to refresh Region `players` relationship to getting actual data?

P.S. if it possible, I want to avoid extra saving to DB, cause I need to perform some actions first (like calculations and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region's `players` relationship is based entirely on objects queried from the database, so it will not "refresh" until the database is updated.

```
db.session.commit()
# now region.players is up to date
```

If you are really concerned with performance, you could use *in memory* `Player` objects to perform whatever actions before saving to the database.

```
players_list = region.players
players_list[0].field = "new value"
# now players_list is up to date while region.players is not
do_calculations(players_list)
# save to db after all calculations are done
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: well, the main problem that using this approach I will commit every second and this is very hard for database. Maybe you can suggest another way ?